# E: Package 'steamcmd' has no installation candidate

Tags: software-installation, 20.04, steam, raspberrypi

Each time I try to install SteamCMD via apt it responds with:

```
Package steamcmd is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'steamcmd' has no installation candidate
```

I have a Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: A quick scan (`rmadison steamcmd`) shows the command is only available for i386 architecture; ie. not a raspberry pi using armv7 or arm64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick scan (`rmadison steamcmd`)

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:/home/wallpapers$   rmadison steamcmd
 steamcmd | 0~20130205-1 | xenial/multiverse  | source, i386
 steamcmd | 0~20130205-1 | bionic/multiverse  | source, i386
 steamcmd | 0~20180105-3 | focal/multiverse   | source, i386
 steamcmd | 0~20180105-4 | groovy/multiverse  | source, i386
 steamcmd | 0~20180105-4 | hirsute/multiverse | source, i386
```

(or via web browser; https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=steamcmd&searchon=names)

shows the command is only available for *i386* architecture; ie. not a raspberry pi using *armv7* or *arm64*.  Your pi has the wrong CPU for `steamcmd`